# Selenium : Selenium Automatically sets referer Header

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

Selenium : Selenium Automatically sets referer Header

I am using selenium RC with chrome

My problem is that each time selenium opens a chrome instance it set the HTTP referer Header to this value 
"name":"Referer",
"value":"https://localhost/selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=534b84df760b4422940a90dadd1bd60c&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fems&debugMode=false"

My web application checks whether referer contains valid link (links which are part of web application) and if referer contains any other link it displays error.

Due to this i am not able to login to my web application using selenium

Is there any way to start selenium instance without "Referer" header or Referer as blank

Answer (score 0):

According [this](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) page there exist this Chrome switch

```
--no-referrers  Don't send HTTP-Referer headers.
```

In Java I would do it like this:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
File file = new File(RegulationUI.class.getResource("/chromedriver.exe").toURI());
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, file.getAbsolutePath());
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); //Chrome starts always maximized
options.addArguments("--no-referrers"); // no HTTP referer will be send
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service,options); //starts Chrome
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //imlpicitly wait 30s for fage to load
```

**EDIT**
I completly missed the Selenium-RC thing. Reading the [javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#DefaultSelenium%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) I realised there can be a way:

```
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("ServerHost", 8080, "path/to/chrome/chrome.exe --no-referrers", "start-url.com");
```

Anyways I never tried it, so I don't know if it will work

**EDIT2**

I foung out, that you can send String to the `start()` command. So if above does not work you can also try:

```
 selenium.start("--no-referrers");
```

Comment: Thanks but i am using selenium RC, do you know how to do this in Selenium RC

Comment: Ahh! Missed that! I am not into the Selenium RC, sorry about that. Maybe if you show me how do you initialize the browser, I could find something...

Comment: I found something in javadoc, hope it helps

Comment: selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,*googlechrome, start-url);   selenium.start();    when searching for this issue i found that in start() we can browser commands, i tried it but was not helpful

Comment: Can you try it with fill path to the chrome binary as I mentioned in the edit?